# How count an variable's frequency in specific column in sas

Tags: sas

I would like to creare a variable along with each subject id, variable is ci_em_ti = COUNT “Impaired” values among the following variables: bvmdrt_cutoff, craftivmmt_cutoff, craftpimmt_cutoff, craftvdelt_cutoff, craftpdelt_cutoff, nlairt_cutoff, nlsdt_cutoff, nlldt_cutoff

How should I do this in SAS?

I tried

```
countc(cats(of bvmdrt_cutoff, craftivmmt_cutoff, craftpimmt_cutoff, craftvdelt_cutoff, craftpdelt_cutoff, nlairt_cutoff, nlsdt_cutoff), "Impaired")`
```

but it done not work

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?  What is the right answer for the posted data?  Please post data as TEXT, not photographs.

Comment: I tried countc(cats(of bvmdrt_cutoff, craftivmmt_cutoff, craftpimmt_cutoff, craftvdelt_cutoff, craftpdelt_cutoff, nlairt_cutoff, nlsdt_cutoff), "Impaired")

Comment: But it didn't work

Comment: Are the variables character? Or numeric with a format attached?

Comment: Did you notice your screenshot shows the word "Impaire" not "Impaired" - the missing D will affect your results. COUNTC() also counts characters, not specific words so this approach does not work.

Comment: When you post data as an image to work with it we have to type it out or make guesses as to what's going on. If you post your code and data as text, it's easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The function `COUNTC()` counts the number of times any of the listed characters appear.  By searching for `Impaired` you are searching for the characters: `adeiImpr`.  So one value of "Missing" will contribute 2 into the count since it has two lowercase i's and "Normal" will count as 3 because the letters r,m and a.  "Imparied" will count as 8 since all of the characters are in the search list.

The function `COUNT()` will search for the number of times a substring occurs so you might try that.

Are you sure your values are character strings?  If instead they are numbers with a user defined format attached the `CATS()` function will not use the formatted values. So you will need to search for the codes instead of the decodes.

PS  There is no need to add the `OF` keyword when there is only one variable in the list.  Either remove the `OF` or remove the commas.

Comment: The "Impaire" makes me fairly sure they're truncated character strings and someone forgot to set the length of the variable.

Comment: Also the values in the image could just be truncated by whatever viewer was being used. 
 For example VIEWTABLE will frequently guess wrong about how wide to create a column for display and show only truncated values.

Answer (score 0):

You say count in a column but then your function is actually counting for several columns but a single row. Since you haven't provided usable data, I'll use SASHELP.HEART instead.
This shows how to display your values in each column.

```
proc freq data=sashelp.heart;
table chol_status bp_status weight_status smoking_status;
run;
```